# getTag() always returns null when called in fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-listview, android-viewpager

I have a problem, because getTag() method returns me null when I call it in fragment which is a part of a ViewPager Tab Layout I created.

#### Code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HistoryFragment extends Fragment {
    ListView listView;
    HistoryAdapter adapter;
    
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View history = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_history, container, false);
        ArrayList<ToSave> arrayOfData = new ArrayList<ToSave>();
        adapter = new HistoryAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), arrayOfData);
        listView = (ListView) history.findViewById (R.id.listView1);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        String myTag = getTag();
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setHistoryFragment(myTag);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "HistoryFragment.onCreateView(): " + myTag, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return history;
    }
}
```

I want to use it for communication between Fragments (add ListView items by clicking a button in another fragment), but I can't make it work.

#### edit

#### TabPagerAdapter.java

```
      @Override
      public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                if (mFragmentAtPos0 ==null) {
                    mFragmentAtPos0 = new PartyFragment(listener);
                }
                return mFragmentAtPos0;
            case 1:
                return new SummaryFragment();
            case 2:
                return new HistoryFragment();
            }
        return null;
      }
```

Comment: Where do you set tag for your fragment?

Comment: Which class exactly TabPagerAdapter extends? Are you also overridig getItemId()?

Comment: I assumed you are using one of the Fragment Adapters and updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Fragment` tags are not automatically specified. You have to assign them yourself. There are several places to do it depending on how you attach fragment: in the XML or dynamically.

If it's define in XML then you can set it like this:

```
<fragment android:name="com.example.news.ArticleListFragment"
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:tag="your_tag"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

If you add fragment dynamically then you can do it like this:

```
ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, "your_tag");
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

In both examples look for **"your_tag"**.

Then when you call `getTag()` on you `Fragment` you will get **"your_tag"** as result.

---

In case use serve your fragments to `FragmentPagerAdapter`, tags are automatically assigned based on `getItemId(int)` which by default returns pager position. So calling `getTag()` would return fragment position in `ViewPager`.

---

In case using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` fragments tags are **NOT** specified. If that's the case you have to switch to first adapter type or use another way to refer your fragments.

From your adapter's implementation I know that you have only 3 pages, so `FragmentPagerAdapter` is more appropriate for you.

As a proof this is a part of description from `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`:

> This version of the pager is more useful when there are a large number
>   of pages, working more like a list view.

and next description from `FragmentPagerAdapter`:

> This version of the pager is best for use when there are a handful of
>   typically more static fragments to be paged through, such as a set of
>   tabs.

---

If you insist using FragmentStatePagerAdapter keep reading:

I assume you need tags to find your fragments later on. Instead tags keep a reference to the fragment. Your Activity's method `((MainActivity)getActivity()).setHistoryFragment(myTag);` already expect a fragment of specific kind. So you could call it like this `((MainActivity)getActivity()).setHistoryFragment(this);` Later, instead of searching fragment, check if it's not null and use it.

Comment: Please, look at my edited post. I don't know how to add the tag in the code I have

Comment: I am using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, but even after Overriding `onCreate()` method like in your post, `getTag()` still returns null.

Comment: @DamianPetla How would you set a tag for a fragment in **XML** which isn't designed using the <fragment ... > syntax? E.g My fragment is inflated using a layout XML file programmattically. Is there any way to set the tag using this method in the onCreateView?

Comment: @Chris-Jr Fragment's `tag` has package visibility and is used only by `FragmentManager`. I don't know why you need tag for anything else. Maybe explain your end goal and I will try to find solution, would be perfect if you post a new question.

Comment: @DamianPetla I actually had figured out what the problem, and the tag began to work. Unfortunately I can't remember what it was now, but thanks for your help.